# Are three points really necessary to georeference?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing

I find myself in a debate between what I have learned and used, and my employer.

Is it possible to get accurate results georeferencing with only two points instead of three or four?

The answers I have gotten range from:

1. No.
2. Yes, if the data is already projected.

I have achieved seamless results georeferencing with two points yet my coworkers think I'm insane or just wrong despite my experience.

Answer (score 21):

The [Fundamentals of georeferencing a raster dataset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-for-georeferencing-a-raster-dataset.htm#GUID-B7FEC41F-BEDC-4B8A-8C5B-BAD6C39619A0) page from Esri explains the fundamentals of georeferencing. In short, the number of points depends. It depends on if you are simply moving the data, scaling, rotating or some combination of all three.

If I am going to shift data that is already correctly scaled and rotated, then I would simply click one point and then another (move this point over here).

> A zero-order polynomial is used to shift your data. This is commonly
>   used when your data is already georeferenced, but a small shift will
>   better line up your data. Only one link is required to perform a
>   zero-order polynomial shift. It may be a good idea to create a few
>   links, then choose the one that looks the most accurate.

If I want to shift, scale and rotate the data then I would need more points.

> Use a first-order or affine transformation to shift, scale, and rotate
>   a raster dataset. This generally results in straight lines on the
>   raster dataset mapped as straight lines in the warped raster dataset.
>   Thus, squares and rectangles on the raster dataset are commonly
>   changed into parallelograms of arbitrary scaling and angle
>   orientation.

If I'm going to warp the image (rubbersheet) then the more points the better. It all depends on the type of georeferencing you're going to perform.

> The higher the transformation order, the more complex the distortion
>   that can be corrected. However, transformations higher than third
>   order are rarely needed. Higher-order transformations require more
>   links and, thus, will involve progressively more processing time. In
>   general, if your raster dataset needs to be stretched, scaled, and
>   rotated, use a first-order transformation. If, however, the raster
>   dataset must be bent or curved, use a second- or third-order
>   transformation.

I suggest reading that page because it contains much more information than what I've provided here.

Comment: I did read that. It didn't answer my question. It does support my employer's position however I have it on authority of a NASA geographer and a college professor that my method is correct. It appears that my answer falls somewhere between c/p'd paragraph one and two. I'm looking for using more than one and less than three control points. You can easily shift, scale and rotate with two points. I've done it hundreds of times. However I wonder if there is a caveat that the projection has to be the same in order for it to work.

Comment: @cpbride Pray tell how you georeference an aerial photo taken from an unknown altitude at an unknown angle with unknown lens distortions using only two points.

Comment: @cpbride yes, the projection has to be the same. You need to have everything in the same plane in order to "georefrence" with pure: moving, scaling and rotating. That is very unlikely. If you have data in an UTM CRS (a known one!) and you want to use another zone you need to go to the long lat coordinates firts and then the new one. The equations are huge and are just approximations. "seamless results" could be a debatable term, I would always state the context. Ask surveyors for long tunnels about geo accuracy

Answer (score 2):

Imho, in general, you should use at least 3 points.

As @Fezter describes, with a single GCP (Ground Control Point), you can only ensure that such single point is correctly referenced, but that can only provide a "translation" transformation after which you know nothing about the surroundings or the orientation. Thus, shall your data be rotated, scaled or warped differently than the target CRS (Coordinate Reference System) you've set, you'd be making mistakes. How large the errors depend on the size and coordinates of the area, and the source and viewing projection you are working on (if any), and also on the operations you do with the poorly referenced objects or raster afterwards.

When you work with already georeferenced data you don't have this problem, because the CRS specifies exactly where ALL the points in the referenced dataset belong in the actual geoid and datum (say, WGS84).

When you don't have that, you need to have as many points as necessary to define the CRS of your dataset. You need at least 3 or 4 (I'm unsure) to account for warping effects, but when dealing with rasters, and because of lens deformation or possible artifacts in orthocorrection or other previous processes (and possibly other effects I'm unaware of), my suggestion is to use a decent amount of GCP (at least 4 but ideally 8 or more) set around the target area (and the more separate, the better).

Even if your data was already projected and you think you can just "move" or "recenter" it with 1 point, projections are rarely coherent or linear, so you may georeference such a dataset with a single point, thinking it's alright, just to discover heavy misalignments a few kilometers away. However, if this was your case, you'd be better off *reprojecting* the data, since you would know your source and target projection in this case, and then you have no need for GCP.

In fact, unfortunately I find many datasets that are slightly misgeoreferenced in an unlinear fashion depending on the area. For example, my country's orthophotos and the national cadastre don't quite match everywhere, despite being officially published under the same CRS.

Regardless of the correctness of the georeferencing, you can yet induce errors on a dataset if you were to apply, say, linear transformations when you should be using spherical ones, or assuming an euclidean space when using projected coordinates to calculate new ones (ie using euclidean distance instead instead of resolving the geodesic problem).

Answer (score 1):

Its that you require at least three points.

Simply describing about it. Take two points of a image. You can georeference them in 2 ways : 1 being in correct up-right format and other rotated in 180 degree(of the mirror image).Third point is thus necessary to make images in correct direction.

Comment: Are you sure? I think that given two points in the original dataset and their corresponding two georeferenced points is enough to resolve rotation.

Comment: The concept of mirror image would be better understanding.

Comment: Ah, that's it. Yes, that better explains it. However, given that most data is sampled from above the ground, I think that particular case is rarely an issue.

Comment: @jjmontes ... but that's because you're *looking* at the image... I work with many automated systems, and absolute minimum is 4. Then you can get error/co-variance.

Comment: Absolutely correct @J.Hirsch

Answer (score 1):

In two-dimensional spaces, knowing two points of the origin plane and where they are mapped, you have 4 degrees of freedom.

With those 4 degrees of freedom you can define a transformation that moves in two directions, rotates and scales evenly, but does not reflect, that maintains the orthogonality of the axes, that does nothing more than what it has freedom to do. And both points will be mapped exactly where they are expected.

For instance, you could define a transformation that moves in two directions and independently scales each axis, but it could not do more than that. And both points will be mapped exactly where they are expected.

Or that it is allowed to rotate and mirror and scale each axis independently, but can't do anything else. And also, both points...

There are many more options because transformations do not have to be orthogonal, they do not have to be affine. They may be the transformation you want, but you cannot define it with more than 4 parameters and a long list of restrictions.

If those 4 degrees of freedom reach you for all other points that will be mapped with that transformation to be accurate, then it will be. If not simply not.